# Explicitly define a column collation even if it's the database default

Tags: sql-server, collation

SQL Server seems to go out of its way to remove a `COLLATE` restriction on a `nvarchar` column if the collation is the DB default.  My DB default is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.  If I create a table thus:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserActive](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
    [Username] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Password] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](254) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserActive] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

... then ask SQL Server Management Studio to script the table as a `CREATE` statement, I get the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserActive](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
    [Username] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](254) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserActive] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Is there any way I can retain the explicit `COLLATE` even if it's the DB default?  I want to be explicit about the fact that any unique index I add on the `Username` column will have that case-insensitive collation, even if the DB default is changed for some reason.  It's nice and self-documenting, which is lost without the explicit collation as part of the table definition.

Comment: Side note: plain-text passwords are a real bad idea. You should salt-and-hash them, and store them in a `varbinary` column. I also can't imagine why it would be null.

Comment: How do you know I'm storing them in plaintext?

Comment: Because they are in an `nvarchar(max)` field. Surely you wouldn't store a binary hash in a Unicode text field? Also the name is a bit telltale, you would normally call it `PasswordHash` or similar to make it more obvious.

Comment: .NET's `PasswordHasher` simply [returns a string](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bec278eabea54f63da15e10e654bdfa4168a2479/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/IPasswordHasher.cs) containing the salted hash.

Comment: Probably because it's used in HTTP headers and the like (where binary values can be a bit weird) so [it returns a Base64 of the hash](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bec278eabea54f63da15e10e654bdfa4168a2479/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs#L99). You can still un-base64 it on the database side to store it. But either way it certainly doesn't need `max`.

Answer (score 5):

SSMS scripting options (Tools-->Options-->SQL Server Object Explorer-->Scripting-->Table and view options) allow you to include the `COLLATE` clause (or not) when scripting objects:

[image: SSMS Scripting options]

Comment: That goes from one extreme to the other, scripting all of them, though.  Also, I suspect it's deriving those default collections from the DB default and the fact that there's no explicit collation on the column.  Is SQL Server actually storing those collations explicitly internally?  Would they all magically change if the DB default were changed?

Comment: @Jez, true but consider that without the collation, the script could be run against a database with a different default collation. The resultant column collation would differ in that case.

Comment: Yeah but I guess I'm thinking that for certain columns that'd be ok, but for others I want the colation to explicitly stay the same.

Comment: @Jez, seems you should keep the source code (scripts) in a version control system rather than reverse-engineering. That would provide full control over the collation clauses.

Comment: I actually do use a VS database project to manage the DB, along with SCMP comparisons.  Annyoingly, their generated script seems to have exactly the same issue.

Comment: @Jez re: "_Is SQL Server actually storing those collations explicitly internally?_" Yes, every string column (`XML` excluded) has an explicitly specified collation. The only times the collation is inferred from the database default is: 1) when creating tables and adding/altering columns, and 2) in queries when `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` is specified. re: "_Would they all magically change if the DB default were changed?_" No, once the column exists, you would need to explicitly `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN` in order to change its collation.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky OK.  Bit of a shame it looks like there's no way to get Visual Studio's DB projects to explicitly script the collation for a column, then, if it's the same as the default DB collation.

Comment: @Jez As should be obvious by now, SQL Server doesn't store if collations are set via `COLLATE` or inferred via DB default. But, even if it did, I still wouldn't want scripting to ignore collations that match the DB default. That would be presumptuous of intent, which can be dangerous. Column collation = the DB default doesn't imply how the app code would behave if the DB default had been different. Some columns might have no impact while others might break things with a different collation. As Dan suggested, schema scripts should originate from source control and not be inferred from existing.

Comment: Visual Studio DB project don't specify the collation explicitly.  Basically, your advice seems to be to avoid using Visual Studio DB project to manage your DB?